# CRM 2011 Security roles - edit many at once?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have new custom entity and I'd like to only Administrator role could add/remove new items to the list. Now I have a lot of Security Roles and I'd like to deny add/remove permission to all of them at once. Is it possible or do I have to deny these one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the XRM toolbox https://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/ It has a module that allows you to edit multiple security roles at the same time.

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed. This tool has a lot of great stuff. You saved me a lot of work :)